# query to count records that are dissimilar from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SRC table and STG table and both tables have a common field called BU. I have written the following query to count records from SRC table where BU and MU in both tables dont match:

```
select COUNT (*) from [dbo].[SRC]
    where ( select Name from [dbo].[SRC] t1, [dbo].[STG] t2 
    where t1.BU <> t2.BU and t1.MU <> t2.MU)
```

Comment: did you forget the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Left join and NOT IN function to get the output.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM  [dbo].[SRC] s
    WHERE s.BU NOT IN (SELECT BU FROM dbo.STG );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join`

```
select COUNT (*) 
from [dbo].[SRC] t1 
left join [dbo].[STG] t2 on t1.BU = t2.BU
where t2.BU is null
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to find matches by `ID` where `BU` and `MU` don't match. You left that out of the question so I'm reading between the lines of some of your comments. I suspect you also only want to see those with a count greater than zero. If any of the `BU` and `MU` columns can be null then you'll need to be careful with those (e.g., `COALESCE(SRC.BU, '!@#$%') <> COALESCE(STG.BU, '!@#$%')`.)

```
select ID, count(STG.ID) as CountDissimilar
from
    dbo.SRC left outer join dbo.STG
        on STG.ID = SRC.ID and STG.BU <> SRC.BU and SRC.MU <> SRC.MU
group by SRC.ID
having count(STG.ID) > 0
```